# Unable to launch Chrome 67 via Selenium WebDriver and ChromeDriver version is 67. Eclipse version is Oxygen M2

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the below mentioned code to launch Chrome version 67 and code compiled successfully but at run time received an exception

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

```
package myproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","/myproject/chromedriver_win32_2.40/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

ChromeDriver version is 2.40 which is latest

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver",....) - 'W' is capital in your code. That could be the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","/myproject/chromedriver_win32_2.40/chromedriver.exe")
```

'W' is capital in your code. That is the error.